# Query with ORDER BY is 13 times as slow when I add LIMIT 1

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have this query (in postgresql):

```
SELECT "table_1".* FROM "table_1"
INNER JOIN "join_table"
  ON "table_1"."id" = "join_table"."table_1_id"
WHERE "join_table"."table_2_id" = 650727
ORDER BY table_1.created_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Which returns 1 result, but is taking ~250-300 ms to execute

There are btree indexes on `table_1.created_at`, as well as `join_table.table_1_id` and `join_table.table_2_id`

When I ONLY remove the `LIMIT 1` from the query, the execution time drops down to ~13ms. This specific query currently only returns one result (without the LIMIT), but there are others with a different value in the WHERE that may return more (which is why the LIMIT is necessary).

Why is adding a LIMIT to a query that is already only returning a single result bloating the execution time so much?

Here is the explain plan with the `LIMIT 1` (these are always hard for me to fully understand...): http://explain.depesz.com/s/rOy

And here is the explain plan without LIMIT 1: http://explain.depesz.com/s/q3d7

Additionally, if I keep the `LIMIT 1`, but change the order by to `ASC`, the query goes down to 13 ms also. And if I change the `LIMIT` to `LIMIT 20` (But keep the `ORDER BY DESC`) it only takes 22ms... wtf!?

So it has something to do with the combination of `ORDER BY DESC`, and `LIMIT 1` (Exactly 1)

Comment: It sounds like you might have index on the column you are ordering by, thus when your order matches the index it is fast and when it is opposite of the index it has to order it in memory before it is able to present the results. Can you list what indexes you have on your tables?

Comment: Did you try looking at the other performance problems on queries with limits for postgres on stackoverflow? There are a lot of topics, maybe those help.

Comment: Do you have 3 indices or 2 with one "composite index" that contains "join_table.table_1_id" as well as "join_table.table_2_id"? With a composite index the join-filtering could be handled entirely by that index.

E.g.: create index join_table_ix1 on join_table (table_2_id, table_1_id);

Answer (score 16):

Ok, this is a pretty classic case.

Whenever you use `LIMIT` (or the like such as `FETCH FIRST ... ROWS ONLY`) the optimizer attempts to optimize the query so that fetching only the first rows(s) is as fast as possible. That means that the optimizer has a preference for execution plans where the first cost value is low, not the second one shown in the execution plan. Remember: the two cost values shown by PostgreSQL (e.g., `cost=48.150..6,416.240` are the setup cost (48.150) and the total execution cost (6,416.240).

The "problem" here is that you have an index which supports your `ORDER BY` clause. So, PostgreSQL thinks that it can just go through this index (in reverse order due to the `DESC` modifier in your query) and check for each row in the other table whether it satisfies the other `WHERE` clause or not. The problem is that the optimizer has no way of knowing whether that will be one of the very first rows or rather one at the end (according to the `ORDER BY`). The optimizer does an arbitrary guess an believes the matching row will be more towards the begin than the end. This optimistic estimate is then used to calculate the cost value which turns out to be too optimistic so that PostgreSQL finally settles down on a bad execution plan.

When you change the `ORDER BY ... DESC` to `ORDER BY ... ASC` the optimizer does the same arbitrary but optimistic estimate which turns out to be more correct in that case, hence you get better execution time.

However, from optimizations perspective, the root cause is that the optimizer estimates that 2,491 rows will match the `WHERE` clause `tango = 650727`. When the optimizer would correctly estimate that this just hits a few rows, then the problem would likely not occur.

The `WHERE` clause is sufficiently trivial that a good estimate should be no problem. So, the main question is: how about your statistics on that table?

There are several ways to cope with this problem:

- Update your statistics ([`ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-analyze.html)) and see if that alone helps.
- Increase the number of most common values stored for that column ([`ALTER TABLE ... SET STATISTICS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html)). This also increases the sample size used to gather the statistics which means `ANALYZE` takes longer but yields more accurate results.

In theory, this should be enough to fix that problem. However, other options are:

- If you don't need the index on `created_at` for other reasons (like other queries), get rid of it.
- Re-write the query so that the bad execution plan is no option any more. In particular, it would be great if you could write the query so that the `ORDER BY` clause uses the same table as the `WHERE` clause: if you are lucky, you might have a column in `join_table` that has the same order as `table_1.created_at` so that it does not make any difference on which you order. However, be careful, this is easy to get wrong (e.g., sequential numbers filled by sequences might have outliners).

Answer (score 0):

Although you are only adding limit 1 but any change to a query affects its execution plan, and indexes used.

To fix your issue, since you are saying that when order is ASC your query performance is good:

It seems the index created on table_1.created_at is ASC.
I know in db2 you can specify when creating an index to be bi-directional ASC/DESC. I guess in postgresql you should have the same, if not you can create 2 indexes on the same field 1 with sort DESC and another wih SORT ASC